# Boundary triangulation induces triangulation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, real-algebraic-geometry

In $R^n$ (the real space) we have an open connected set $D$, such that $\partial D$ is triangulable. Can we prove the closure $\bar{D}$ is triangulable or any counterexample?

Furthermore, the $\partial D$ are piecewise algebraic in the question I am considering, I do not know whether this would be helpful for the above statement.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If $\partial D$ is piecewise algebraic, then there seem to be an obvious way to proceed: find a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^n$ taking $\partial D$ to a locally finite union of affine simplices, and extend the latter to a triangulation of $\mathbb R^n$, which in particular, should triangulate $\bar D$.

Comment: Is there any standard way to build the homeomorphism, or how to find this kind of homeomorphism? Is it by gluing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I had all the references I would post it as an answer. Even the case when $\partial D$ is smooth is nontrivial (but course classical). I would search online for "extending a triangulation real algebraic". Once this is done take a regular neigborhood of the subcomplex. Its boundary would be a PL submanifold and you can then extend a triangulation as in Igor Rivin's answer.

Comment: Here is a reference: see theorem 4.1 in https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/handle/2027.42/63851, "Triangulation of Locally Semi-Algebraic Spaces", by Kyle Hofmann (The result is not proved there; rather it points original references).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many categories, the answer is known to be yes, [see](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403055.pdf)

*Emil Saucan*, MR 2184196 [**Note on a theorem of Munkres**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00009-005-0040-z), *Mediterr. J. Math.* **2** (2005), no. 2, 215--229.

Comment: I have read the note, and find they are all applied to $C^r$ manifold with boundary. But in my question, the boundary is only piecewise smooth (algebraic), i.e. no $C^r$ structure on the boundary. Will those results still be true (by approximation)?

Comment: If the boundary is algebraic, the whole set must be semi-algebraic, and Hironaka's result should apply.

Comment: That would be cool for algebraic part. But which Hironaka's result are you pointing to? Can you kindly offer some reference? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @lunzhang this one? https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/3a549739-3274-4640-901b-40d9e58e9a71/49651c3ab5d8482b4790488e5140fea1

Comment: Good. That seems to be what I try to find.

Answer (score 3):

Although you do not seem to require that the triangulation of the closure to
be compatible with the triangulation of the boundary, it is
true in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that a triangulated polyhedron $P$ has a compatible
interior tetrahedralization. Bern proved that, if $P$ has $n$ vertices,
such a tetrahedralization by $O(n^2)$ tetrahedra exists (and can be found quickly):

> Bern, Marshall. "Compatible tetrahedralizations." *Fundamenta Informaticae* 22.4 (1995): 371-384. ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=161151).)

In fact, he proved all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be tetrahedralized compatible with
$P$'s surface triangulation (with some tetrahedra having a vertex at $\infty$).

It is interesting that if you change "triangulable" to "hexahedral-able,"
and ask if the surface mesh can be extended compatibly to an interior mesh, 
the answer is unknown:

> "No algorithm is known to construct
>   hexahedral meshes compatible with an arbitrary given quadrilateral
>   mesh, or even to determine when a compatible hex mesh
>   exists, even for the simple examples shown in Figure 1"

---

[image: JeffE1]

---

> Erickson, Jeff. "Efficiently hex-meshing things with topology." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 52.3 (2014): 427-449. ([PDF download](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/pdf/hexmeshx.pdf).)

Comment: So all the above statement for the $\mathbb{R}^3$ space, right? Indeed, I do not require compatibility of triangulation, but want result in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general

Comment: @lunzhang: Yes, my references are only to $\mathbb{R}^3$.